# Trouble with the sonar-packaging-maven-plugin after refactoring

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, sonarqube

I have some trouble developing a plugin for my company, later called as "myPlugin".

**Background:** 
I was reading the book "SonarQube in Action" by the Manning company.
There was a little guide for developing a own plugin (they used the redmine plugin as example for developing). It told me to use the sonar-plugin-archetype to create the basic framework.

**Situation before refactoring:** 
I wrote the plugin and it works fine. I encountered the problem when I've done some refactoring. Before the refactoring every package in the src folder in my tree (using ecplise) was called "main.java.org.sonar.plugins.myplugin" but the package decleration within each class was "org.sonar.plugins.myplugin". This were default settings created by using the sonar-plugin-archetype.

The settings within the pom.xml of the sonar-packaging-maven-plugin were the following once.

```
Pom-snippet before any changes were done:
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
   <configuration>
     <pluginClass>org.sonar.plugins.myplugin.myPlugin</pluginClass>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So far everything worked fine. Now we come to my problem.

**Situation after refactoring:** 
As my company has some naming conevtions for classes and packages i changed the package names in the tree to "com.mycompany.sonar.plugins.myplugin" and the package decleration within each class also to "com.mycompany.sonar.plugins.myplugin". Then i changed the classPath option for the sonar-packaging-maven-plugin to "com.mycompany.sonar.plugins.myplugin.myPlugin". All I've done so to say was changing "org." into "com.mycompany.".

```
Pom-snippet after changes were done:
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
   <configuration>
     <pluginClass>com.mycompany.sonar.plugins.myplugin.myPlugin</pluginClass>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When i was running the "compile" command everything worked. Using "package" does not work, because the sonar-packaging-maven-plugin was not able to find the given class (see console output below). When i'm refoactoring everything again back to the beginning it works again.

```
[...] 
[INFO] --- sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.9:sonar-plugin (default-sonar-plugin) @ sonar-projectkeychecker-plugin ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.649 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-02T11:42:01+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/67M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.9:sonar-plugin (default-sonar-plugin) on project sonar-myplugin-plugin: Plugin class not found: 'com.mycompany.sonar.plugins.myplugin.myPlugin-> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**My Question:** Why are my new names not working? Are there any inner convetions for the sonar-packaging-maven-plugin (like the packaging name has to beginn with "org.sonar" ot something like this)?

Thank you for reading this long text and your try to help me :)

Comment: Can you provide the new POM snippet?

Comment: what exactly do you want to see? i added it to my question (i made already sure there are no typing mistakes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pluginClass is the entry point of the plugin. Value must be an existing class. In your example I suppose that there's a typo, it should be com.mycompany.sonar.plugins.myplugin.MyPlugin (upper-case M).

Comment: As you may know: for real these classes are called not the same as they are called here. 

But as i said: the pluginClass points on an existing class. I also made sure there are no typing mistakes or anything like that.
The package path and the Plugin class exists both. The "upper-case M" idea is not the reason for failling (in my real project i made sure the class-name begins with an upper-case letter).

Comment: In fact sonar-packaging-m-p does not search for the class in project classpath. It checks that the related .class file exists in the build dir, so you should verify that the file ${project.build.outputDirectory}/com/mycompany/sonar/plugins/myplugin/MyPlugin.class exists when the m-p is executed.

Comment: I checked it... and you are right! For some reason .class datas are not created while using another package decleration then the given one. Not even with the "compile" command... But however: thats not part of my question. Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score -1):

Under `<plugin>` I was missing the `<extensions>true</extensions>` tag